# How to make a posed mesh respect collisions?

Tags: animation, rigging, soft-body

My softbody sphere "remembers" its collision with another object even after moving it away in pose mode. Why does it happen and how do I make an armature-parented object collide with something?
[image]

Comment: it would help if you explain what you have done. What are the soft body settings and  what's the order of the modifiers on the stack? How does the animation look like? Is the big sphere just moved along the Y axis towards to the other sphere and then back?

Comment: @Blunder thank you, the modifiers were in an incorrect order

Answer (score 1):

So turns out the armature modifier has to be above softbody. I'm leaving the question up so maybe it helps someone.